# Undefined control sequence. \IEEEpubid with ieeetran

Tags: pdftex, ieeetran, copyright, ieeeconf

I had a problem when I insert these lines just before or after the `\begin{document}`

```
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts

\IEEEpubid{\makebox[\columnwidth]{978-1-5386-1842-4/17/\$31.00~\copyright{}2016 IEEE \hfill}\hspace{\columnsep}\makebox[\columnwidth]{ }}
```

example:

```
\documentclass[conference,a4paper]{ieeetran}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{subeqnarray}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\parskip 1mm
\arraycolsep 0.5mm
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newcommand{\sign}{\mathrm{sign}}
\newcommand{\sat}{\mathrm{sat}}

\title{International Conference on Image Processing Theory, Tools and Applications}

\author{\authorblockN{Author\authorrefmark{1}, Author\authorrefmark{1} and Author\authorrefmark{2} }
\authorblockA{\authorrefmark{1} Affiliation 1\\
e-mail: author-1@ieee.org, author-2@ieee.org}
\authorblockA{\authorrefmark{2} Affiliation 2\\
e-mail: author-3@ieee.org}}

\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts

\IEEEpubid{\makebox[\columnwidth]{978-1-5386-1842-4/17/\$31.00~\copyright{}2016 IEEE \hfill}\hspace{\columnsep}\makebox[\columnwidth]{ }}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

I have this error `Undefined control sequence. \IEEEpubid`

here is the template that I use [template latex](http://www.ipta-conference.com/ipta16/images/latex-style-template.zip)

**Update**

I have compile it using texShop editor and it generates the copyright lines in a new pages.
[image]

Comment: @Mico, to prepare the camera-ready version, the conference staff give us these instructions! we have to add these two line just before \begin{document}

Comment: @Mico, please see my update.

Comment: See the answer I posted. The solution turns out to be quite simple: Use `\pubid{...}`, not `\IEEEpubid{...}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IPTA conference staff gave you some incorrect information. When using the `ieeetran` document class (the file `ieeetran.cls` is distributed with the template you're using), after first running `\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts`, you must run `\pubid{...}`, not `\IEEEpubid{...}`.

I can only guess that the IPTA conference staff got confused over terminology used by the `IEEEtran` document class, which uses `\IEEEpubid`, and the `ieeetran` document class (note the lowercase letters "ieee"), which uses `\pubid`. Since you're using the `ieeetran` document class, you must use `\pubid`.

As a public service to other conference participants, you may want to contact the IPTA staff and let them know (a) that they're giving out incorrect information and (b) what the correct information is. :-)